# Getting JS/JQuery/CSS plugins to work in ASP.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to the ASP.net MVC world, prototyping a website idea atm.

Anyway, I'm struggling to add a simple plug in to my cshtml page views.

For example I wanted to add this slider: http://loopj.com/jquery-simple-slider

So I added the necessary plugin to the source base and added them in BundleConfig.cs

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

Nothing worked.

I added the css stuff to the base.css file thinking for some reason I'm misssing something, so instead directly added to base.css, no changes.

I feel like I'm missing something like a 101 tutorial atm.

Really not sure where to dig next to get something so fundamental working...

Comment: Check in firebug if all necessary script libs are added and if there's any error.

Comment: I would suggest to read this http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification. This is article about bundling and minification in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, I think I will do just this!

Answer (score 0):

If you can request for the plugin's js/css but it's not working, maybe you are not importing jQuery **first** before the plugin. Else, there's something wrong with your path.